# Unlocking lock takes too long

Tags: java, locking

I have an object which is protected by a `ReadWriteLock`.

```
final ReadWriteLock pendingRequestsLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
final Lock pendingRequestsReadLock=pendingRequestsLock.readLock();
final Lock pendingRequestsWriteLock=pendingRequestsLock.writeLock();
```

The problem is that sometimes (seems to be random and rare) unlocking the write lock takes too long (4-10ms on an Intel i7 2.6GHz CPU). I measure the unlocking time like this:

```
Long time2=System.currentTimeMillis();
pendingRequestsWriteLock.unlock();
Long unlockTime=System.currentTimeMillis()-time2;
if(unlockTime>1)System.out.println("Unlock time: "+unlockTime);
```

The thread which uses the write lock is being started periodically (every 100ms).

**Question**:
What is the reason behind the long unlock times? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Avoid it by avoiding locks. They are expensive, particularly read-write locks. There are almost certainly other ways to achieve it, maybe post the code that uses the locks if you want suggestions to avoid the locks.

Comment: Also, I don't understand "The thread which uses the write lock is being started periodically (every 100ms)." Better if you post your whole benchmark test as these are often floored.

Comment: Avoiding locks is not an option as we are speaking about a multithread application. There are 3 threads using the same object. 2 of them mostly just reads it, that is why I use ReadWrite lock. The third thread which is a scheduled job runs every 100ms. This one acquires the write lock at the beginning of its task and releases at the end. Acquiring a lock can take long, I understand that. But why does it need 8ms to release it?

Comment: I do not have a benchmark test. I just measure how much time is needed to execute the 'pendingRequestsWriteLock.unlock();' call, which sometimes needs 4-8ms. See my 2nd code block in the question.

Comment: "Avoiding locks is not an option" I've written dozens of multithreading apps. I've never had to use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. There are other options which may suit your application better.

Comment: If that's not a benchmark then the time taken is unexplainable by anyone here given what we know of the system, it's down to other threads and how they are interacting with the lock.

Comment: I'd look at the source code of `unlock`. You will see it does a lot, it's wrong to assume that unlocking is cheap.

Comment: So without knowing much more about your app, have you tried, and what was wrong with, an application of a simple `synchronized` block?